# The coordinates of top 10 values of a grid

Tags: algorithm, fortran

I have a 3D grid of size `NxNxN`. In an array called `data` of dimension `N**3` I have scalar values stored corresponding to each grid point. Can anyone suggest a FORTRAN program which gives me the coordinates of T points of the grid, which have the top T values of `data` in a CSV format?

The output should be something like this,

```
x1,y1,z1,value1
x2,y2,z2,value2
...............
...............
x9,y9,z9,value9
x10,y10,z10,value10
```

It will be nice if the values are in the sorted order.

Comment: not yet. let me read about it. "Edit: " but even with this, it doesn't look very trivial :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Yossarian's suggestion I threw away my old answer and offer this much improved version instead.  Most of the credit is due to Yossarian though.

```
PROGRAM sort

  USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_fortran_env

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ne = 50
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: tops = 10

  REAL(real64), DIMENSION(ne,ne,ne) :: data_array
  LOGICAL, DIMENSION(ne,ne,ne) :: mask_array
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(tops,SIZE(SHAPE(data_array))) :: top_array
  INTEGER :: ix

  CALL RANDOM_SEED(put=[1])
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(data_array)

  mask_array = .TRUE.

  DO ix = 1, tops
     top_array(ix,:) = MAXLOC(data_array,mask=mask_array)
     mask_array(top_array(ix,1),top_array(ix,2),top_array(ix,3)) = .FALSE.
  END DO

END PROGRAM sort
```

Now, at the end of the program `top_array` contains the indices of the largest `tops` elements of `data_array`.

I still have doubts about this being as efficient as a well-written sort routine, but I have tested it on arrays up to `512^3` elements and it runs in a reasonable time.

Comment: Nice! This is pretty much exactly what I had in mind. I agree, it probably is not the most efficient way of doing things - it needs to do the sorting `tops` times, throwing away the sorting done at the previous iteration. There's probably a fortran sorting library out there, if this needs to be repeated many times.